# angular form checkbox touched

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form with a save button that is disabled until the form is touched. All the inputs are working with this except a checkbox, no matter how many times I click/change the checkbox the form always says untouched. Is this expected behavior?

```
<form name="form" id="my-info" #myinfo="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="autoAssign" name="autoAssign" [(ngModel)]="updatedSettings">
    <label for="autoAssign">
      Checkbox auto assign
    </label>
  <div>
  <button (click)="save()" [disabled]="myinfo.invalid || (!myinfo.dirty || !myinfo.touched)">
    Save
  </button>
</form>
```

I'm not sure why the disabled logic is the way it is - it was written previously by someone else, but the point is, when I render the value of `myinfo.touched` it's never true when I keep checking / unchecking the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some digging, looks like this is expected behavior per this github page: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23308